# JMS can not connect to websphere mq

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

this is code of my class java

---

```
package com.ibm.point_A_point;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

/**
 * A minimal and simple application for Point-to-point messaging.
 * 
 * Application makes use of fixed literals, any customisations will require re-compilation of this
 * source file. Application assumes that the named queue is empty prior to a run.
 * 
 * Notes:
 * 
 * API type: JMS API (v1.1, unified domain)
 * 
 * Messaging domain: Point-to-point
 * 
 * Provider type: WebSphere MQ
 * 
 * Connection mode: Client connection
 * 
 * JNDI in use: No
 * 
 */
public class SimplePTP {

  // System exit status value (assume unset value to be 1)
  private static int status = 1;

  /**
   * Main method
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Variables
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    Destination destination = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;
    MessageConsumer consumer = null;

    try {
      // Create a connection factory
      JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
      JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

      // Set the properties
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "localhost");
      cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");
      cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM1");
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "SimplePTP (JMS)");

      // Create JMS objects
      connection = cf.createConnection();
      session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      destination = session.createQueue("queue:///Q1");
      producer = session.createProducer(destination);
      consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

      long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
      TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("SimplePTP: Your lucky number today is "
                                                      + uniqueNumber);

      // Start the connection
      connection.start();

      // And, send the message
      producer.send(message);
      System.out.println("Sent message:\n" + message);

      Message receivedMessage = consumer.receive(15000); // in ms or 15 seconds
      System.out.println("\nReceived message:\n" + receivedMessage);

      recordSuccess();
    }
    catch (JMSException jmsex) {
      recordFailure(jmsex);
    }
    finally {
      if (producer != null) {
        try {
          producer.close();
        }
        catch (JMSException jmsex) {
          System.out.println("Producer could not be closed.");
          recordFailure(jmsex);
        }
      }
      if (consumer != null) {
        try {
          consumer.close();
        }
        catch (JMSException jmsex) {
          System.out.println("Consumer could not be closed.");
          recordFailure(jmsex);
        }
      }

      if (session != null) {
        try {
          session.close();
        }
        catch (JMSException jmsex) {
          System.out.println("Session could not be closed.");
          recordFailure(jmsex);
        }
      }

      if (connection != null) {
        try {
          connection.close();
        }
        catch (JMSException jmsex) {
          System.out.println("Connection could not be closed.");
          recordFailure(jmsex);
        }
      }
    }
    System.exit(status);
    return;
  } // end main()

  /**
   * Process a JMSException and any associated inner exceptions.
   * 
   * @param jmsex
   */
  private static void processJMSException(JMSException jmsex) {
    System.out.println(jmsex);
    Throwable innerException = jmsex.getLinkedException();
    if (innerException != null) {
      System.out.println("Inner exception(s):");
    }
    while (innerException != null) {
      System.out.println(innerException);
      innerException = innerException.getCause();
    }
    return;
  }

  /**
   * Record this run as successful.
   */
  private static void recordSuccess() {
    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
    status = 0;
    return;
  }

  /**
   * Record this run as failure.
   * 
   * @param ex
   */
  private static void recordFailure(Exception ex) {
    if (ex != null) {
      if (ex instanceof JMSException) {
        processJMSException((JMSException) ex);
      }
      else {
        System.out.println(ex);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("FAILURE");
    status = -1;
    return;
  }

}
```

---

I have always this error(exception)
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: Authentication security provided to the queue manager 'QM1' with the connection mode 'Client' and the hostname 'localhost (1414) 'was invalid.
Check if the user name and password provided are correct in the waiting queue manager to which you connect.
The WebSphere MQ call failed with the completion code '2' ('MQCC_FAILED'); pattern '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').

Comment: You should probably provide a username and a password to connect to the queue.

Comment: but how get the password and user name ?

Answer (score 2):

You need user id and password (depending on version of MQ) to  connect to queue manager. This user id would typically exist on the machine where the queue manager is running.

You will need to pass the user id and password as below in your code. Replace with your user and password.

```
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID,"userid"); 
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, "password");
```

Apart from this the user must be given authority to connect to queue manager, put/get on the queue your application is using.

I suggest you speak to your MQ administrator to provide the user id/password information as well as required authorities.

Answer (score 2):

```
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");
```

You should not be using a SYSTEM channel.  Ask your MQAdmin to create one for your application.

```
connection = cf.createConnection();
```

Change it to:

```
connection = cf.createConnection("myUser","myPswd");
```

Ask your MQAdmin if the authentication is targeted to either Local OS or LDAP and then use the appropriate UserID and Password.